# How do I move a file from a directory containing a specific number into a different directory?

Tags: shell, command-line, grep, xargs

I want to move all my files from a folder that have the numbers 1995, 1996, and 1997 to different folders.

Much of what I've found on this list has to do with moving any file that contains any pattern. I want the command to look in the directory, scan the .txt file's contents, and as soon as they find 1996, put it in the 1996 directory.

This means that if the command looks in the directory, scans the .txt file, and finds 1996 on the first line AND finds 1995 on the tenth line, it doesn't put the file in BOTH the 1996 and 1995 folders. I want it to only put the file in the 1996 folder.

```
grep -rl --null --include '*.txt' 1996 . | xargs -0 sh -c 'cp "$@" /folderpath' sh
```

This seems to put 1995 files into the 1996 folder just because it contains 1995 somewhere in the file.

Comment: I don't understand. What does the first files contain? So what I get is: 1) for each file in a directory 2) you want to check if the file contains the number 1995 on the first line 3) if it does, put it inside 1995 folder 4) repeat step 2 and 3 for numbers 1996 and 1997. right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this could work:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print0 |
xargs -0 -n1 sh -c '
    if a=$(head -n1 "$1" | grep -o "199[567]"); then
        mv "$1" "./$a"
    fi
' --
```

Alternatively the `xargs` can be substituted with `while IFS= read -r file; do` loop. That would look like:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print0 |
while IFS= read -r file; do
    if a=$(head -n1 "$file" | grep -o "199[567]"); then
        mv "$file" "./$a"
    fi
done
```

- `find` finds everything

  - `.` - in the current directory
  - `-name '*.txt'` - with names ending with `.txt`
  - `-print0` - and prints them as zero terminated list
- `|` - pipe, passes the output of one command to another
- `while` - executes a `do ... done` body until the command returns non-zero exit status
- `IFS= read -r file` - a popular mnemonic to read zero separated list, see [bashfaq How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

  - `head -n1 "$file"` - extract first line from the file
  - `grep`

    - `-o` - output the matched string only
    - `199[567]` - match `1995` or `1996` or `1997`
    - `grep` outputs a zero exit status if it matches successfully (important at `if`)
  - `a=$(...)` - assign the output of the command to `a`. The exit status of the process substitution `$(...)` is the last command executed, `grep` in this case.
  - `if command` - executes the `then ... fi` body only if the command returns with a nonzero exit status. Ie. here only if grep matches the string successfully, it will return a zero exit status.

    - `mv "$file" "./$a"` - the variable `a` (bad naming...) contains the string that `grep` matched so it will be `1995` or `1996` or `1997. So move the file to proper folder.

Comment: Where do I put the new filepath? And is every reference to "1" in reference to the first line, or only references to "$1"?

Comment: 1) [man find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) replace the `.` dot in path. 2) I don't understand, you might test it out. `echo 1 | xargs -n1 sh -c 'echo "$1"' --` I don't get what is a "reference to "1"" or reference to $1? You can add `-t` option to `xargs` to debug it.

Comment: So say I want to find 1996 on every 3rd line of the file. Do I put in ```find . -name '*.txt' -print0 |
xargs -0 -n3 sh -c '
    if a=$(head -n3 "$3" | grep -o "1996"); then
        mv "$3" "/$a"
    fi
' --```

Comment: Please read the documentation. [man head](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/head.1.html) [man xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) `xargs -n3` passees 3 files to the sh at a time, you want to run it for each file, so `-n1`. `head -n3` would extract first 3 lines. You could do `head -n3 "$1" | tail -n1` to extract the 3rd line only. It may be easier for you to see it with  a `while read` loop rather then xargs, so I edited the answer.

Comment: I added some explanation too.

Comment: I'm getting an error: ```mv: rename .filename to /1996: Permission denied```

Comment: Well, `permission denied`. The `/1995` looks suspicios, did you forget about the `.` in `./`?

Comment: I got it. Thank you!